# check if netcdf library supports netcdf4

Tags: c, netcdf, netcdf4

Does anyone know if there is a way to check at runtime or user compile time if a netcdf library build includes support for netcdf4?

There is a function `nc_inq_libvers()` but the version number itself is not useful because modern library versions can still be built with netcdf4 support turned off.

I simply want to be able to write code that checks if netcdf4 is supported, if it is then create a netcdf4 file, if not then create a netcdf3 file.

Answer (score 0):

**Ideal approach**:

Investigate the library's source code for some `#define`s that you can check either at compile-time or at run-time (you may have a look also at the library's building process, in order to spot if such defines are made).

Then it's trivial to check for support; for instance, if the library defines `NETCDF4_SUPPORT_ENABLED`:

```c
// compile-time check
#ifdef NETCDF4_SUPPORT_ENABLED
  int main(void) {
    // use netcdf4 format...
  }
#else
  int main(void) {
    // use netcdf3 format...
  }
#endif
```

---

**More complex approach**: (in case the library doesn't make such `#define`s)

You need to change your program's configuration/building procedure. When you'll build your program, a script written by you may check if the NETCDF library has been compiled with NETCDF4 support; in case support is enabled, your configuration script may add, for instance, parameter `-DNETCDF4_SUPPORT_ENABLED` to the command you use to compile your program, so this can be handled like in the previous solution.

Writing a script that detects if the NETCDF library has NETCDF4 support enabled is up to you, and different solutions work for different libraries.

A really (really) dirty hack, to only use in case of nuclear attack, is to write a small C program like this (that your configuration script will try to compile in order to detect NETCDF4 support):

```c
#include <assert.h>
static_assert(sizeof( foo() ) != sizeof(int), "NETCDF4 support is not available");
// NOTE: replace `foo` with a library function that doesn't return `int` (nor another type with the same size of `int`)
// this code will fail to build if function `foo` is missing
```

Replace `foo` with the name of a library function that *won't* be included in the library if NETCDF4 support is disabled (also, the function's return type size must be different from `int`'s size, e.g.: it may return `long long`, `char`, `void`, etc).

But I think a better solution may be found for the specific case of the NETCDF library (the previous hack is library-agnostic, but really dirty).